# Is it possible to have a large cell in the middle of a Bootstrap 3 grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, css-grid

Is it possible to have a larger nested cell that spans rows and columns using the Bootstrap 3 Grid CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need any bootstrap. You only need to setup one cell using `grid-area`. More about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

Browsers support of `grid-area` https://caniuse.com/#search=grid-area thanks to [Gerard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3132019/gerard)

```css
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 5px;
grid-row-gap: 5px;
min-height: 300px;
}

.grid > div {
background: #ccc;
}

.grid > div.my-big-sell {    
grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 6;
background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="my-big-sell"> </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just be careful with [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid-area)

Comment: Oh my, so I don't even need Bootstrap grid for this. Incredible. I guess it's time to learn CSS Grid

Comment: Updated answer with browser support link, thanks to @Gerard. To better understand how grid-area works - try this generator https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/.

Comment: Is it possible to make the CSS Grid responsive without media queries? e.g. as the browser width reduces, the number of columns reduces from 6 to 5, and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately - no. And with `grid-template-columns` you'll have to update `grid-area` too (for 5 cols `grid-area` will be `2 / 2 / 4 / 5` in this case)